# Append user text with 'enter' key into ul (chat box) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a chatbox with jQuery.
I want to attach a `li` that contains the user text to `ul` using 'Enter' key
 (without PHP or any server), but it's not working.

My code looks like this:

```
var txt = "<b>me:</b>"+$(".usertext").val();
var myli = $("<li>").html(txt);
$('chav_box_in').keypress(function(e) 
{
    if ( $(".usertext").val() != "" )   
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $("#send").click(function(){
                $("#chatlog").append(myli);
                $(".usertext").val("");
            })
        }
    }
});
```

[My chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP4zX.png).

Comment: Missing something in `$('chav_box_in')`???

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a click event listener on your #send element each time you do a enter keypress, not actually firing that event.

If you are meaning to do a enter keypress and do a Send button click to add the messages you can make a single function and pass it as an argument to jQuery event listener methods

```
function appendChat(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    //variables for testing, you could have all of the
    //comparisons in the 'if' statement, just using these to
    //make the 'if' statement more clear
    var notEmpty = $(".usertext").val() != "",
        isEnterKeypress = e.type == "keypress" && e.keyCode == 13,
        isSendClick = e.type == "click" && id == "send";

    if( notEmpty && (isEnterKeypress || isSendClick) ) {
       var txt = "<b>me:</b>"+$(".usertext").val();
       $("#chatlog").append($("<li>").html(txt));
       $(".usertext").val("");
    }
}

$("#send").click(appendChat);
$(".chav_box_in").keypress(appendChat);
```

Demo

```js
function appendChat(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  var notEmpty = $(".usertext").val() != "",
      isEnterKeypress = e.type == "keypress" && e.keyCode == 13,
      isSendClick = e.type == "click" && id == "send";

  if( notEmpty && (isEnterKeypress || isSendClick) ) {
    var txt = "<b>me:</b>"+$(".usertext").val();
    $("#chatlog").append($("<li>").html(txt));
    $(".usertext").val("");
  }
}

$("#send").click(appendChat);
$(".chav_box_in").keypress(appendChat);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="chatlog"></ul>
<input class="usertext chav_box_in"><button id="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: thank u ,
by the way.. if I press 'Enter' its attach and also down to another line

Comment: @EylonYizhack, you could try using `keydown` event instead and make a `e.preventDefault()` call in the callback to prevent the new line

Answer (score 1):

You can't have event inside an event.

Remove that click event from keypress keeping code in there.

```
 $('.chav_box_in').keypress(function(e) 
{

    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        if ($(this).val ()!=""){

                $("#chatlog").append(myli);
                $(".usertext").val("");
        }   
        }


});
```

Comment: like this?
   $("#send").____?____(function()

Comment: I added a code. Using mobile so adjust my indentation